# Раскрывающийся pie chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Раскрывать элемент диаграммы по которому кликнули. На входе такой массив, где child - это это те элементы, которые надо раскрыть.

```
data = [{"label":"Расходы", "value":1000}, 
        {"label":"Доходы", "value":2000}, 
        {
            "label":"Другое", 
            "value":500, 
            "child":[
                {"label":"Другое 1", "value":400},
                {"label":"Другое 2", "value":70},
                {"label":"Другое 3", "value":30},
             ]
        }];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После клика должно быть что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var w = 300,
h = 300,
r = 100,
color = d3.scale.category20b();

data = [{"label":"Расходы", "value":1000}, 
        {"label":"Доходы", "value":2000}, 
        {
            "label":"Другое", 
            "value":500, 
            "child":[
                {"label":"Другое 1", "value":400},
                {"label":"Другое 2", "value":70},
                {"label":"Другое 3", "value":30},
            ]
         }];

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data]) 
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {

    });

    arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) 
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
            .attr("stroke", "#fff");

    arcs.append("svg:text")                                     
            .attr("transform", function(d) {                   
            d.innerRadius = 0;
            d.outerRadius = r;
            return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";       
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .attr("fill", "#fff")  
        .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].label; });
```

```css
slice{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле идея проста. Нужно всего лишь определить arc, на который кликнули, и на его месте отрисовать дочерний pie chart.

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235
- http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6872886

```js
const w = 300
const h = 300
const r = 150
const color = d3.scale.category20b();
const offset = 20

const data = [{
    "label": "Расходы",
    "value": 1000
  },
  {
    "label": "Доходы",
    "value": 2000
  },
  {
    "label": "Другое",
    "value": 500,
    "child": [{
        "label": "Другое 1",
        "value": 400
      },
      {
        "label": "Другое 2",
        "value": 70
      },
      {
        "label": "Другое 3",
        "value": 30
      },
    ]
  }
];

const vis = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .data([data])
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");

const arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(r - offset)
  .innerRadius(0);

const arcChild = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(r)
  .innerRadius(r / 2);

const pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(d => d.value);

const pieChild = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(d => d.value);

const arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'slice')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    // если нет дочерних полей, игнорим
    if (!('child' in d.data)) {
      return
    }

    // берём настройки текущего arc,
    // чтоб рисовать не полный круг,
    // а только нужную область
    const {
      startAngle,
      endAngle
    } = d;
    const self = d3.select(this)

    // настраиваем углы в дочернем pie chart
    pieChild.startAngle(startAngle).endAngle(endAngle)

    // удаляем целый arc с родительскими данными
    self.selectAll('path').remove()
    self.selectAll('text').remove()

    // рисуем дочерние arc
    const childs = self
      .selectAll('g.child')
      .data(pieChild(d.data.child))
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'child');

    childs.append("path")
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i + 10))
      .attr("d", arcChild)
      .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
      .attr("stroke", "#ccc");
  });

arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
  .attr("stroke", "#fff");

arcs.append("text")
  .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "#fff")
  .text((d, i) => data[i].label);
```

```css
svg {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все действительно легче, чем я пытался сделать. А можно как-то восстановить родительский элемент при нажатие на child? И как передать цвет родителя, чтобы все child были такого же цвета?

Comment: @xenon Цвет объявляется как `color(i)`, соответственно попробуйте пробросить родительский индекс. Родительский элемент можно отрисовать заново, точно также: удалить все дочерние чарты и нарисовать path + text. Либо можно поступить умнее и использовать кэширование через скрытие неиспользуемых элементов.